# Advanced/custom Doctrine ORM relations (TYPO3 translated entities)

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm in the unfortunate position of maintaining a TYPO3 project. The TYPO3 "ORM" is really slow and awkward to use and so I want to use Doctrine ORM for some of my read operations.

TYPO3 has a pretty weird way of storing translations and so my tables look something like this:

```
> products
 id
---
123
 64
 37

> product_names
product_id | locale | name
----------------------------------
        64 | en     | My Product
        64 | de     | Mein Artikel
```

Assuming the current locale is always available in some kind of magic global variable, is there a way to map this to the following class in Doctrine ORM? (Basically adding a static `AND locale = "en"` to the `JOIN` condition. Or maybe in a custom Type? Or some kind of proxy? I don't know.)

```
class Product {
    private string $id;
    private ProductName $name;
}

class ProductName {
    private string $name;
}
```

Obviously, I can't really change anything about the database or the class structure since TYPO3 expects it this way.

Currently, my only idea is to use an event subscriber to add some kind of proxy for the name in `postLoad`, but that would have the significant overhead of having a separate DB query every time the product name needs to be accessed - for every single product.

Answer (score -1):

That structure is not the usual way TYPO3 handles translations.

Normaly translations are handled by a copy of the original record (in the same table) but with a pointer to the original (`l18n_parent`) and a field indicating the current language (`sys_language_uid`).

Additional TYPO3 handles languages not by locales but in declared language uids. So the same id can stand for different languages in different installations.

For me your datastructure seems to be imported from somewhere else.

Comment: I tried to simplify/clarify it for the non-T3 folks. Yes, I have `sys_language_uid` and `l10n_parent`, but that doesn't change the nature of my question. (Which you didn't answer in the slightest.)

Comment: If you have real TYPO3 structures, try to optimize TYPO3 instead of inserting something external to optimize only one query, which might conflict with TYPO3 caching and prevent later updates.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me from the T3 sideof things, but that wasn't what I was looking for at all. I want to get away from any frameworks as much as possible, not tie myself to them even more.